# JavaFX 2.0 - create action handler for custom component in FXML

Tags: custom-controls, javafx-2, fxml

I want to add a custom action in my new component. 
How to do this?

Example code:

Component

```
public class MyCustomComponent extends Region {
    public MyCustomComponent(){
        super();

        this.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                /* throw my custom event here and handle it in my FXML controller - but how? :-(  */
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public class MyController {
    @FXML protected void myCustomAction(ActionEvent event) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

FXML:

```
<BorderPane fx:controller="fxmlexample.MyController" 
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
     <top>
        <MyCustomComponent onAction="#myCustomAction">
        </MyCustomComponent>
     </top>
</BorderPane>
```

Thx for help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to implement property in your custom component, which will store your `action`.

```
public class MyCustomComponent extends Region {
    public MyCustomComponent(){
        super();

        // just to find out where to click
        setStyle("-fx-border-color:red;");
        setPrefSize(100, 100);

        this.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                onActionProperty().get().handle(event);
            }
        });
    }

    // notice we use MouseEvent here only because you call from onMouseEvent, you can substitute any type you need
    private ObjectProperty<EventHandler<MouseEvent>> propertyOnAction = new SimpleObjectProperty<EventHandler<MouseEvent>>();

    public final ObjectProperty<EventHandler<MouseEvent>> onActionProperty() {
        return propertyOnAction;
    }

    public final void setOnAction(EventHandler<MouseEvent> handler) {
        propertyOnAction.set(handler);
    }

    public final EventHandler<MouseEvent> getOnAction() {
        return propertyOnAction.get();

    }    
}
```

and don't forget to add import in your fxml file:

```
<?import my.package.MyCustomComponent?>
```