# Set custom control's Button "onAction" method in the FXML file?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I created a new custom control containing labels, text field and a button. How can I set custom control's Button "onAction" method in the FXML file?

Example code:

```
<BorderPane fx:controller="fxmlexample.MyController" 
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
 <top>
    <MyCustomComponent onButtonAction="#myCustomButtonAction">
    </MyCustomComponent>
 </top>
```

Comment: You need to expose a method from your custom control which fire's the button and then use it in FXML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution. I did it exactly as Sergey Grinev suggested in this thread - [JavaFX 2.0 - create action handler for custom component in FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964638/javafx-2-0-create-action-handler-for-custom-component-in-fxml). The only change I made was using my button's field name instead of "this" in Class constructor.

Answer (score 0):

`onButtonAction="#myCustomButtonAction"` can be used as long as `MyCustomComponent` contains a setter for the event handler named `setOnButtonAction`.

```
class MyCustomComponent {

    private Button button;

    public void setOnButtonAction(EventHandler<ActionEvent> handler) {
        this.button.setOnAction(handler);
    }

    public EventHandler<ActionEvent> getOnButtonAction() {
        return this.button.getOnAction();
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. But I found a solution (in my answer).

Comment: @notmyf4ulty sorry, forgot that the getter is required for the `FXMLLoader` to get handler type. Should work now...