# Custom action emitter property for custom component JavaFX - How?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

In the midst of developing a JavaFX application project, this is my first real stumper and I don't even know how to properly say what I'm trying to do because I don't know the names of the techniques I'm trying to utilize.

In my application, I have multiple custom components so I can build a more complex scene. This problem involves 3 control components; a PrimaryControl component (SplitPane) which contains a MenuComponent and an ActivityComponent (both custom) which changes based on the selection of radio buttons set up in the MenuComponent.

How can I get the MenuControl class to "emit" the performed action when a radio button in the ToggleGroup (from that component) is changed which will then be handled by a function in the parent component PrimaryControl so that it may change which ActivityComponent is visible/active? Bear with me.

primary_control.fxml

```
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.VBox" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <MenuControl onToggleGroupButtonSelectionChanged="#onChange"/>
    <ActivityOneControl fx:id="one" isVisible="true"/>
    <ActivityTwoControl fx:id="two" isVisible="false"/>
    ...
</fx:root>
```

menu_control.fxml

```
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.VBox" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.2-internal">

    <GridPane alignment="CENTER" hgap="10" vgap="10">
        <padding><Insets bottom="25" left="25" right="25" top="15" /></padding>
        <Label text="Select A Task" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0">
            <font><Font name="System Bold" size="13.0" /></font>
        </Label>

        <fx:define>
            <ToggleGroup fx:id="menuSelection"/>
        </fx:define>

        <RadioButton fx:id="one" text="one" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1" toggleGroup="$menuSelection">
        </RadioButton>
        <RadioButton fx:id="two" text="two" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2" toggleGroup="$menuSelection">
        </RadioButton>
        <RadioButton fx:id="three" text="three" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="3" toggleGroup="$menuSelection">

        </RadioButton>
    </GridPane>

</fx:root>
```

How do I create a listener in my MenuControl java class that will be able to detect the ToggleGroup selection change, then emit that change to `onToggleGroupButtonSelectionChanged="#onChange"` so I can handle the button selection from the PrimaryControl java class? I remember doing this type of thing in Angular and it was pretty easy but for some reason, I can't find any information on how to do this is Java. Is this what's known as dependency injection?

I found this link and tried to implement for my problem but unsuccessful as nothing was explained and a different event was being listened for [JavaFX 2.0 - create action handler for custom component in FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964638/javafx-2-0-create-action-handler-for-custom-component-in-fxml).

PrimaryController.java (same as MenuControl.java)

```
public class PrimaryControl extends VBox {

    public DashboardControl() {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("primary_control.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }

    @FXML
    protected void onChange() {
        System.out.println("change activity");
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance to anyone helping me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, create an enum that represents the possible selections:

```java
public enum SelectionMode {
    ONE, TWO, THREE
}
```

- Now, add a property to your Menu control that gives other controls the ability to know what is selected without exposing the logic behind it or making it changeable from other controls (using `ReadOnlyObjectProperty`) :

```java
private ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<SelectionMode> selectionMode
    = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(this, "selectionMode");

public final ReadOnlyObjectProperty<SelectionMode> selectionModeProperty() {
    return selectionMode.getReadOnlyProperty();
}

private final SelectionMode getSelectionMode() {
    return selectionMode.get();
}
```

- Bind this property to the selected radio button in the Menu controller class's `initialize` method. Note that I am using `setUserData` and `getUserData` methods, otherwise, you need to need to have an if clause for each radio button you have:

```java
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    one.setUserData(SelectionMode.ONE);
    two.setUserData(SelectionMode.TWO);
    three.setUserData(SelectionMode.THREE);

    selectionMode.bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
        Toggle selectedToggle = menuSelection.getSelectedToggle();
        return (SelectionMode) selectedToggle.getUserData();
    }, menuSelection.selectedToggleProperty()));
}
```

- Your Primary controller class can access its Menu controller by setting an id in `<MenuControl fx:id="menu"/>`.
  Then you can just assign a `ChangeListener` and get notified every time the selection is changed:

```java
menu.selectionModeProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    // write your code here
});
```

**Note**: you can initialize user data in your fxml like this (instead of doing it in `initialize` method):

```xml
<RadioButton fx:id="one" text="one" toggleGroup="$menuSelection">
    <userData>
        <SelectionMode fx:constant="ONE"/>
    </userData>
</RadioButton>
<RadioButton fx:id="two" text="two" toggleGroup="$menuSelection">
    <userData>
        <SelectionMode fx:constant="TWO"/>
    </userData>
</RadioButton>
<RadioButton fx:id="three" text="three" toggleGroup="$menuSelection">
    <userData>
        <SelectionMode fx:constant="THREE"/>
    </userData>
</RadioButton>
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand the logic but the code is a little confusing. What class is the initialize method overriding from? I get an error from the @Override because there isn't a method to override (it also isn't getting called). Also does the `ChangeListener` go in the constructor after or before the `fxmlLoader.load()`? I put the `enum` in my menuController and I'm getting `NoSuchFieldException`, is this the proper spot for it?