# onAction="#handleButton1" not working in JavaFX FXML

Tags: java, javafx

I use IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3 and JavaFx17.

I am trying to change the screen that appears, but the program does not even open. Because of onAction button cannot resolve the handleButton1. I create the screens in SceneBuilder I added the controller class and I add the button function in the import button but it is not working.

My Controller Class

```
package com.example.family_tree;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Controller {
    Stage stage;
    Scene scene;
    Parent root;

    @FXML
    //Button createButton, importButton;

    public void handleButton1(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("import.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root, 750, 750);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Main Class

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root,750,750));
        stage.setTitle("Family Tree Application");
       // stage.initStyle(StageStyle.DECORATED);

        stage.show();
        stage.setResizable(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

and the fxml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.Cursor?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.ColorAdjust?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane focusTraversable="true" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="719.0" prefWidth="1217.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.family_tree.Controller">
   <children>
      <VBox layoutY="-7.0" prefHeight="719.0" prefWidth="310.0" style="-fx-background-color: #26a69a;">
         <children>
            <Pane prefHeight="234.0" prefWidth="309.0">
               <children>
                  <Label alignment="TOP_LEFT" layoutX="48.0" layoutY="164.0" prefHeight="56.0" prefWidth="207.0" text="FAMILY TREE  " textAlignment="CENTER" textOverrun="CLIP">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="Symbol" size="33.0" />
                     </font>
                     <effect>
                        <ColorAdjust brightness="-0.54" contrast="0.45" hue="-0.96" />
                     </effect>
                     <cursor>
                        <Cursor fx:constant="TEXT" />
                     </cursor>
                  </Label>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="87.0" layoutY="14.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@family_tree.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </children>
            </Pane>
            <Button alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" graphicTextGap="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="309.0" style="-fx-background-color: #0097A7;" text="CREATE FAMILY TREE">
               <padding>
                  <Insets left="50.0" />
               </padding>
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial" size="15.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" graphicTextGap="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButton1" prefHeight="56.0" prefWidth="309.0" style="-fx-background-color: #0097A7;" text="IMPORT FAMILY TREE">
               <padding>
                  <Insets left="50.0" />
               </padding>
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial" size="15.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" graphicTextGap="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="56.0" prefWidth="309.0" style="-fx-background-color: #0097A7;" text="HELP">
               <padding>
                  <Insets left="50.0" />
               </padding>
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial" size="15.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" graphicTextGap="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="56.0" prefWidth="309.0" style="-fx-background-color: #0097A7;" text="MADE BY" wrapText="true">
               <padding>
                  <Insets left="50.0" />
               </padding>
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial" size="15.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </VBox>
      <Button layoutX="587.0" layoutY="208.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="339.0" prefWidth="339.0" style="-fx-background-color: #4CAF50;">
         <graphic>
            <ImageView fitHeight="339.0" fitWidth="391.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@Adsız.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
         </graphic>
      </Button>
      <Pane layoutX="309.0" layoutY="82.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="907.0">
         <children>
            <Label layoutY="-14.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="907.0" style="-fx-background-color: #26a69a;" text="CREATE NEW FAMILY TREE" textAlignment="CENTER">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Times New Roman" size="31.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </Pane>
      <VBox layoutX="983.0" layoutY="208.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*Create action handler for custom component in FXML*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9964638/230513).

Comment: Please post [mre]. All you need to demonstrate the problem is one button in the fxml. All the rest can be removed. Also, you code includes two fxml files but only one is posted.

Comment: You have the wrong import for `ActionEvent` in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mix Swing/AWT code and JavaFX code by mistake (and usually not intentionally either).

Don't write:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
```

Do write:

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
```